# How can I prevent "type" stdout from appearing while running my script?

Tags: bash, scripting, debian

I am currently working on a script that needs to check if a program is installed when it first starts up. If the program is not present, the script will proceed with doing whatever is necessary for the installation of the program. I have tried the following so far:

```
program_exist=$( type "someprogram" | grep "not found" )
if ! "$someprogram_exist"; then
        do some stuff
fi

program_exist=$( type "someprogram" 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "not found" )
if ! "$someprogram_exist"; then
        do some stuff
fi
```

but each time I run this, I am always met with the following message:

```
./some_program.sh: line 8: ./some_program.sh: line 7: type: someprogram: not found: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to check for the existence of a program without having it display the `./some_program.sh: line 8: ./some_program.sh: line 7: type: someprogram: not found: No such file or directory` message each time?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Comment: thanks! there were some good suggestions on that page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try this :

```
if ! type someprogram &>/dev/null; then
    do_some_stuff
fi
```

or shorter :

```
type someprogram &>/dev/null || do_some_stuff
```

Comment: thanks! looks like the way I had my 'if' statement setup was causing some issues, though it works like a charm now